# Why is Vezos Habracha divided into 7 portions?

Tags: simchat-torah, parashat-vezot-habracha

On Simchas Torah only 6 people are called up to the Torah for Vezos Habracha [unless they repeat the aliyahs to give everyone one etc.]

the question is, in all chumasheem that I'm aware of, Vezos Habracha is divided into 7 sections, not 6. Why is this?